# name a file using a record in the database using vbs

Tags: vbscript, recordset

well, i´m trying to make a visualscript which creates a file where a recordset is written in it and the name of the file is as a record of the database, to put an example, I want a query, the query is written in the file, and the name of the file is one of the rows of a table, here is my code:

```
Dim Filename 
Dim Connection 
Dim commandoSQL 
Dim Archivo 
Dim Nombre 
Dim objFSO 
Dim outputFile 

Call Main
Sub Main
    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call startConnection()  Set commandoSQL = Connection.Execute("select rest_def.obj_num, hdr_def.line_01, hdr_def.line_02, hdr_def.line_03, hdr_def.line_04, hdr_def.line_05, hdr_def.line_06, trlr_def.line_01, trlr_def.line_02, trlr_def.line_03, trlr_def.line_04, trlr_def.line_05, trlr_def.line_06, trlr_def.line_07, trlr_def.line_08, trlr_def.line_09, trlr_def.line_10, trlr_def.line_11, trlr_def.line_12 from rest_def inner join hdr_def on hdr_def.obj_num rest_def.obj_num inner join trlr_def on trlr_def.obj_num = hdr_def.obj_num where hdr_def.obj_num = 101")
    'Archivo = "D:\archives\"
    Set Filename = Connection.Execute("Select obj_num FROM rest_def")
    Nombre = Filename.getString
    Archivo = "D:\archives\" + Nombre + ".txt"
    Set outputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Archivo,True)
    outputFile.Write commandoSQL & vbCrLf
    outputFile.Close
    Call closeConnection()
End Sub

Sub startConnection()
    Set Connection = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Connection.Open "DSN=milo; UID=dataBase; PWD=password"
End Sub

Sub closeConnection()
    Connection.Close 
End Sub
```

So if the data of Filename is 7890, I want the file to be named as 7890.txt with all the recordset written in the file... help please, this is my first attempt with vbs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use ADODB objects in VBScript I'd recommend reading the [ADO API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086(v=vs.85).aspx) first to familiarise yourself the various objects.

In this particular case the line

```
Set Filename = Connection.Execute("Select obj_num FROM rest_def")
```

returns a [`ADODB.Recordset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx) object, to access the results of the query you would use the `Fields` collection and either pass an ordinal position of the returned field in this case `0` or a named field which would be `obj_num`.

That would change this line from

```
Nombre = Filename.getString
```

to

```
Nombre = Filename.Fields("obj_num").Value
```

Also there is no such method as `getString()` for the `ADODB.Recordset` object.

Changing the `Main()` sub procedure to

```
Sub Main
    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call startConnection()
    Set Filename = Connection.Execute("Select obj_num FROM rest_def")
    'Continue to iterate through the recordset until we reach the last
    'record (EOF).
    Do While Not Filename.EOF
        Nombre = Filename.Fields("obj_num").Value & ""
        Archivo = "D:\archives\" & Nombre & ".txt"
        Set outputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Archivo, True)
        outputFile.Write commandoSQL & vbCrLf
        outputFile.Close
        'Move to next record
        Call Filename.MoveNext()
    Loop
    Call closeConnection()
End Sub
```

should work. It depends if you want to create a file for each record returned but from your limited explanation this is my interpretation.